# Show that the process created from taking kth steps of a markov chain is markov.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose $(X_n)_{n\geq0}$ is a Markov chain with transition probability matrix $P$ and initial distribution $\lambda$. Show that the process $Y_n = (X_{kn})_{n\geq0}$ with $k$ fixed is Markov with transition probability matrix $P^k$. What is the initial distribution?

I know all the general tricks for finding probabilities of nth steps through powers of the matrix and such, but I am not sure how to approach this one!

SMALL DISCOVERY: 
So of course the initial distribution $\lambda$ is a vector of length $n$ (if we have $n$ possible states) ie we can write

$\lambda = (\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n)$ where $\lambda_i = \mathbb{P}(X_0 = i)$

So I guess as we have $X_0 = Y_0$ the initial distributions are both $\lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $Y_0=X_0$ so the initial distribution is still $\lambda$. As for the Markov property, for any nonnegative integers $0\leqslant t_1<t_2<\cdots<t_n$,
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(Y_{t_n+1}=j | Y_{t_n}=i_n, \ldots, Y_{t_1}=i_1) &= \mathbb P(X_{k(t_n+1)}=j |X_{kt_n} = i_n, \ldots, X_{kt_1}=i_1 )\\
&= \mathbb P(X_{k(t_n+1)} = j | X_{kt_n}=i_n)\\
&= \mathbb P(Y_{t_n+1} = j | Y_{t_n} = i_n).
\end{align*} $$

Further, this probability is
$$\mathbb P(X_{kt_n+k} = j | X_{kt_n}=i_n) = (P^k)_{ij}. $$

Comment: Ok, so I was missing the key trick of transferring from $Y_n$ to $X_n$ using the Markov property of $X_n$ but instead "the present state" is k steps ago compared to 1 step ago in the normal chain. Simple enough! Would we keep Markov properties if we took a general subsequence of markov chain, say like the (3$n$+5)th steps with natural $n$? obviously there would be some issues with the probability matrix.

Comment: I think it would be the same, although if $Y_n = X_{kn+m}$ then $Y_0=X_m$. So the initial distribution of would be the distribution of $X_m$.